# What does the speaker imply in "piecrust collar" and "smell of horse"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, implication

I could not understand the implication in this sentence, especially the "**piecrust collars and smell of horse**". I am totally lost! Could anyone help please?

The context is :

Will (a quadriplegic in wheelchair) and I (his carer) are going to the wedding of Will's ex-girlfriend, who is going to marry Will's former best friend. It's obvious I don't want him to go to the wedding, because I was worried for him. Nathan is Will's medical carer.

The sentence is :

> ……and there was Will, in a dark suit and a cornflower-blue shirt with
>   a tie. He was clean-shaven, and carried a faint tan on his face. The
>   shirt made his eyes look peculiarly vivid. They seemed, suddenly, to
>   carry a glint of the sun.
>
> ‘Not bad,’ I said—because, weirdly, I didn’t want to say how handsome
>   he actually looked. ‘She’ll certainly be sorry she’s marrying that
>   braying bucket of lard, anyway.’
>
> Will raised his eyes heavenwards. ‘Nathan, do we have everything in
>   the bag?’
>
> ‘Yup. All set and ready to go.’ He turned to Will. ‘No snogging the
>   bridesmaids, now.’
>
> ‘As if he’d want to,’ I said. ‘They’ll all be wearing **piecrust
>   collars and smell of horse**.’
>
> *Me Before You by Jojo Moyes*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the 1980s and later, blouses or dresses with a 'pie crust' collar were popular among young women of the British upper class. There is a stereotype that such women spend a lot of time riding horses. The carer is speaking disparagingly of the social background of the bridesmaids.

[image]

Comment: ha, that's why. I was wondering why the style has anything to do with horse . thank you so much:)